# Angular 2 - calling class methods in template loop *ngFor

Tags: angular, typeerror

I have an angular2 app where the component class is getting a little to big.
I've decided to create a folder with 'Handler' classes, so i could put the related code in each handle class. In my component class i then create an instance of each handler and use these in the template

My component:

```js
export class DesignerComponent {
public tab: TabHandler = new TabHandler(this);
```

My handler:

```js
export class TabHandler {

public designerComponent: DesignerComponent;

constructor(designerComponent: DesignerComponent)
{
    this.designerComponent = designerComponent
}

add() {
    if (this.designerComponent.formModel.tabs.length < 1) {
        this.designerComponent.formModel.tabs.push(new TabModel("Tab"));
    }
    this.designerComponent.formModel.tabs.push(new TabModel("Tab"));
}
```

My template:

```html
<li *ngFor="let tab of formModel.tabs; let i = index; ">
  <a href="#" [ngClass]="{'tab-selected': formModel.currentTab == tab}"
    class="tab-button"
    attr.contenteditable="{{formModel.currentTab == tab}}"
    (blur)="tab.changeShortTitle($event)"
    (dragover)="allowDrop($event,'tab')"
    (dragstart)="drag($event,i,'tab')"
    (drop)="drop($event,i)"
    (dragleave)="dragleave()"
    (click)="tab.select(tab)">
    {{tab.shortTitle}}
  </a>
</li>
<li id="add-tab-buttonholder">
  <a href="#" (click)="tab.add()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</li>
```

the last `<li id="add-tab-buttonholder">
                        <a href="#" (click)="tab.add()`

works because it's outside of the *ngFor loop.

I have tried to create an empty function in the class, and call it in the lopp, but that also fails with the same error message

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.$implicit.select is not a
>   function

Comment: You should change your template.. instead of calling `add()`, you should call `tab.add()`. But without seeing your template, this is hard to answer

Comment: I do use tab.add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop variable has the same name as the `TabHandler` in your class. Your loop variable overrules the class member inside the loop, that's why it can't execute the `select` method on it.

I'd suggest renaming the `TabHandler` since only `tab` is misleading anyway:

```ts
export class DesignerComponent {
    public tabHandler: TabHandler = new TabHandler(this);
```

And in your template:

```html
<li *ngFor="let tab of formModel.tabs; let i = index; ">
    <a href="#" [ngClass]="{'tab-selected': formModel.currentTab == tab}"
        class="tab-button"
        attr.contenteditable="{{formModel.currentTab == tab}}"
        (blur)="tab.changeShortTitle($event)"
        (dragover)="allowDrop($event,'tab')"
        (dragstart)="drag($event,i,'tab')"
        (drop)="drop($event,i)"
        (dragleave)="dragleave()"
        (click)="tabHandler.select(tab)">
            {{tab.shortTitle}}
    </a>
</li>
<li id="add-tab-buttonholder">
    <a href="#" (click)="tabHandler.add()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Think i need a brake when these error are not found :)